# Execute Package Utility and SSIS .dtsx package files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a .dtsx package that i deploy to the file system (File System Deployment) using the Integration service deployment manifest file package installation wizard.

The Package and its package configuration file are deployed to the selected folder successfully. 
If i then browse to the deployment folder and double click the package, the Execute Package Utility is launched and i can execute the package from that tool.

PROBLEM:

If i repeat the above procedures on my production server, then browse to the deployment folder and double click the package, a cmd window just pops up for a couple of seconds but the Execute Package Utility is never launched. So i can't run the package by double clicking it.

But on the Server, if i connect to Integration Services from management studio, browse to stored packages, right click File System and then import the package from its deployment folder into Integration Services, i am able to right click the package, then click run package and here the Execute Package Utility is launched and the package execution will complete successfully.

I am just wondering why double clicking the package will launch the Execute Package Utility on my dev machine but won't on the server?

Comment: I also have the projects Run64BitRuntime property set to false, not sure if this might be related.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the server may not have the DTEXECUI application set as the default program for the file type *.dtsx. Once that association is made, you should be able to double click and execute the package with that application.